# What is wrong with my username?

Tags: technical-issues, dungeons-and-dragons-online

Picture: [image]
I was signing up for Dungeons and Dragons Online, and I picked `DnDMaster111` as my username. I got an error (this was the only error) that said my username was not valid, because a valid username can only have a-zA-Z1-9_,. I might just be tired, but I'm pretty sure my username doesn't violate any of that. Is this a bug, or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a space before or after the name?

Comment: No, I'm positive.

Comment: Makes me wonder if they block names with "DnD" in it.

Comment: I tried DDMaster111, and same thing.

Comment: Oh, <an unrelated name>Master111 worked.

Comment: @Powerlord sounds like it.  They could have Mod accounts that are prefixed with DND so it could be blocked for that reason.